# osmdroid: messed up tiles shown when loading custom tilesource

Tags: java, android, android-studio, osmdroid

I try to show tiles from my custom tileserver.
I'm using my own tileserver (shown at https://www.url.be)
Tiles are shown correct here.
I just don't understand why my tiles are messed up on the android studio app (using osmdroid). The problem persists when zooming in too.

See this screenshot[image]

And my code:

```
map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
// Create a custom tile source
map.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("hot", 1, 20, 256, ".png",
new String[] { "https://www.url.be/hot/" }) {
    @Override
    public String getTileURLString(long pMapTileIndex) {
        return getBaseUrl()
        + MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)
        + "/" + MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)
        + "/" + MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)
        + mImageFilenameEnding;
    }
});

//map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
IMapController mapController = map.getController();
mapController.setZoom(15.0);
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(51.111500, 3.985040);
mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
```

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have been looking further on this issue.
I had to switch the getY and getX in the code.

So:

```
return getBaseUrl()
                        + MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)
                        + "/" + MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)
                        + "/" + MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)
                        + mImageFilenameEnding;
```

Had was wrong and should be:

```
return getBaseUrl()
                        + MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)
                        + "/" + MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)
                        + "/" + MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)
                        + mImageFilenameEnding;
```

Hope this helps anyone